# Why does this `random()` execute only once?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

```
from random import random

def printNumber(num=random()):
    print num

for i in range(10):
    printNumber()
```

I want to see ten random numbers, but the ten random numbers are all the same!

Comment: @delnan Sorry, I've already searched `[python] execute once`, but I didn't find that post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the default arguments are only executed once, when the function is compiled.

From the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function):

> Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is
>   executed. This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the
>   function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used
>   for each call. T

you can try something like this:

```
In [10]: def printNumber(num=None):
    return num if num is not None else random()
   ....: 

In [12]: printNumber()
Out[12]: 0.9620725546432438

In [13]: printNumber()
Out[13]: 0.8188258892156928

In [15]: printNumber(10)
Out[15]: 10
```

Comment: Is this typical for Python or is this mechanism (default value only assigned once) more widespread? Please back up with examples.

Comment: @Michael not sure about other languages but in python it's a normal behavior.(may be not for new programmers). See [this](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm#why-does-this-happen).

Comment: @Michael I know C++ does the other thing (adds the default expression at each call site), but that has its own problems, and it doesn't make a lot of sense to compare C++ to Python here because they are so fundamentally different. Google indicates Ruby also creates a new value each time though.

Comment: @delnan Thank you for the info. I try to compare the mechanisms themselves, of course we can't judge about this in a few sentences. :)

Answer (score 3):

because it is executed at function inststanciation ... not on function call

the correct(er) way would be

```
def printNumber(num=None):
     if num == None:
         num = random()
         print num
```